# Using awk or sed to compare value of two files and append information from file 2 to file 1 to a new file file3

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have 2 files: File 1 and File 2. I want to check and compare the file name in File 1 and file 2 and where they match, insert into file_1 the numbers from file_2 into a new File_3 using only awk or sed.

I have tried using

```
cat file.2 | while read line do
```

[image: The files 1 and 2 with expected output]

Comment: Please post a small part of each file and the expected output here, and what have you attempted to get a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { d[$NF]=$1; next } d[$NF] { print d[$NF] FS $0 }' FILE2 FILE1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define function by yourself to check file by ne one.

```
checkDiff() {
   file1=$1
   file2=$2
   result=$3
   rm -rf $result
   #check Which one is big based line count
   file1Count=$(cat ${file1}  | wc -l)
   file2Count=$(cat ${file2}  | wc -l)
   # to check which one need to pass to while loop
   if [ $file1Count -gt $file2Count ] ; then
        bigFile=$file1
        smallFile=$file2
   else
        bigFile=$file2
        smallFile=$file1
   fi
   #check difference line by line
   cat $bigFile | while read line ; do
       notpint=$(cat $smallFile | grep  "$line")
       if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then           # if you want to print where they match change "ne" to "eq"
           echo $line >> $result
       fi
   done
   }
```

### #

```
checkDiff <file1> <file2> <result filename>
```